# Update multiple files upload with CarrierWave

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have implemented the "multiple file uploads" in my model just like explained in the documentation of CarrierWave and it's working just fine. My problem is that I can't get the model update working. When I try to add new files it removes the old ones. I'd like to keep both. Here is part of my model and controller:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :photos, PhotosUploader
end

class AlbumController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @album = Album.new(album_params)
    if @album.save
      flash[:success] = 'Album created'
      redirect_to @album
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    if @album.update_attributes(album_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Album created'
      redirect_to @album
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def album_params
      params.require(:album).permit({ photos: [] })
    end
end
```

I thought about putting the photos in a different model but if I could make it work this way would be better. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I have the below in my update method to ensure existing images (avatars) uploaded by CarrierWave remain in tact. I have a separate method that allows users to individually delete images.

```
 def update
    project_params_holder = project_params
    project_params_holder[:avatars] += @project.avatars if project_params_holder[:avatars]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params_holder)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```